# How to stop event listener?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome app in React and have run into an issue of excessive re-renders. In `popup.js`, `console.log('this is triggered');` displays exponentially until crash as a user navigates to different urls. I've seen this behavior before and believe it has to to with `eventListeners`.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074850/chrome-runtime-onmessage-call-multiple-time) post, @wOxxOm mentions `You add new listeners in chrome.runtime.onMessage each time a tab is updated. Extract the callback into a top-level function.`

This is what I believe is causing the issue. However, I'm not sure what is meant by `Extract the callback into a top-level function`.

The desired functionality is for the current url to be tracked each time it is changed. That way the app can see what page the user is on and display information accordingly.

Any idea how to prevent the excessive re-rendering? Thank you!

EDIT: Here's an [image](https://snipboard.io/eiG2E4.jpg) of what I'm seeing

EDIT 2: I commented out all the the react code until I was able to diagnose where the issue was happening.

The issue is occuring anytime a state variable is set/updated inside the `chrome.runtime.onMessage` function.

For example the below function causes excessive re-renders:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender) {
    if (msg.message == 'currentUrl') {
    console.log('this is triggered');      
      setCurrentUrl(msg.url);
    }
  });
```

The same also happens if another function that updates state is called:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender) {
    if (msg.message == 'currentUrl') {
    console.log('this is triggered');      
    testFunction()
    }
  });

const testFunction = () => {
  setState()
}
```

**popup.js**

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender) {
    if (msg.message == 'currentUrl') {
    console.log('this is triggered');      
      setCurrentUrl(msg.url);

      if (isLoggedIn) {
        extractZendeskId(msg.url);
      }
    }
  });
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  //Wait until page is fully loaded
  if (tabId === tab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
    // Now the tab is ready!
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
      message: 'currentUrl',
      url: tab.url,
    });
  }
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'toggle');
});
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.bundle.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon-34.png"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.bundle.js"],
      "css": ["content.styles.css"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "popup.html",
    "content.styles.css",
    "icon-128.png",
    "icon-34.png"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.firebase.com https://apis.google.com https://www.gstatic.com; object-src 'self'"}
```

Comment: Please add minimum reproducible example (I suspect it is caused by react component, should be in popup, but do not see any react code). Also I would investigate if re-rendering component in popup raises a tab update event, causing it to loop (plausible but not sure), see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added EDIT 2 with more information. Essentially, the issue is occuring anytime a state update is set inside the chrome.runtime.onMessage. I'm going to dig deeper into component re-rendering thought because that sounds like it could be it as well